# Navigation bar not working html

Tags: html, navbar

I am making a navigation bar using HTML.  I have all of my files together, but it's not working.

Do you know why it wouldn't be working?

```html
<!——Navigation Bar Starts here!—->
<hr>
  <center>
<h3 style="word-spacing:50px">
 <a href src="ContactInformation.html">Contact_Information</a>
 <a href src="ProductInformation.html">Product_Information</a>
 <a href src="Index.html">Index</a>
</h3>
  </center>
<hr>

<!——Navigation Bar Ends here!—->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have invalid links, try something like

```
<a href="ProductInformation.html">Product_Information</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it!

```
<hr>
  <center>
<h3 style="word-spacing:50px">
 <a href="ContactInformation.html">Contact_Information</a>
 <a href="ProductInformation.html">Product_Information</a>
 <a href="Index.html">Index</a>
</h3>
  </center>
<hr>
```

Comment: lol, simple errors right?